# data splitting in training testing validation sets in Matlab 2010

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, matlab

my question is: Matlab 2010 provides options of Testing, Validation periods in Neural Network process. is this data splitting or will i have to use "crossvalind" for data splitting?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an excerpt from the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/nnet/ug/bss33zw-1.html#bss33zw-9):

> When training multilayer networks, the general practice is to first
>   divide the data into three subsets. The first subset is the training
>   set, which is used for computing the gradient and updating the network
>   weights and biases. The second subset is the validation set. The error
>   on the validation set is monitored during the training process. [...]
>   The test set error is not used during training, but it is used to
>   compare different models. [...]

There are four functions provided for dividing data into training, validation and test sets: `dividerand`, `divideblock`, `divideint`, and `divideind`. (actually there is a fifth `dividetrain` that assigns all instances to training)

[image: table]

For more sophisticated methods (cross-validation, stratification, etc..), check out `cvpartition` or `crossvalind` functions.